# Batch. Trying to make text adventure, if else not working

Tags: batch-file, variables, if-statement, input

i am trying to make a text adventure, but i'm kind of clueless how to get an if/else statement to work with a variable. probably a few mistakes in my code:

```
@ echo off

color 0a

echo This is a text adventure! to play, read through the story and at certain points you get to make decisions.

echo Remember, selecting an invalid option will automatically be counted as option 2!

echo have fun

pause

cls

echo You wake up in a dimly lit room. You can't seem to remember anything. Anything about you or how you got here, that is.

echo You walk towards the door. It is locked.

echo 1)Force the door open.

echo 2) look around for another means of escape.

set /p escape=

if %escape% = 1

cls 
echo you get the door open, but an orc comes in and smashes your face.

echo get rekt buddy, game over.

pause

exit
else

goto dungeon


:dungeon

cls

echo well done.

pause

exit
```

Comment: Ever bothered to read the help of `if` (type `if /?` into a new command prompt window)?

Answer (score 0):

If your `if` statement has has an accompanying `else` statement, you need to use parentheses. The else **must** also be in the format `) else (`, like this:

```
@ echo off
color 0a
echo This is a text adventure! to play, read through the story and at certain points you get to make decisions.
echo Remember, selecting an invalid option will automatically be counted as option 2!
echo have fun
pause
cls
echo You wake up in a dimly lit room. You can't seem to remember anything. Anything about you or how you got here, that is.
echo You walk towards the door. It is locked.
echo 1)Force the door open.
echo 2) look around for another means of escape.
set /p escape=
if "%escape%"=="1" (
    cls 
    echo you get the door open, but an orc comes in and smashes your face.
    echo get rekt buddy, game over.
    pause
    exit
) else (
    goto dungeon
)

exit /b

:dungeon
cls
echo well done.
pause
exit
```

I've removed the blanks lines for aesthetic purposes; you can put them back in if you really want them. I also added a `exit /b` because having a `goto` followed by the label you're going to is bad form. The quotes in the `if` statement are there to prevent the script from breaking if the user enters nothing.